# Identify some SMD components

Tags: identification, surface-mount

I need to identify some SMD component.

COMPONENT 1:
Markings are T5 and G7. 
Seems package is DFN 6.

COMPONENT 2:
Markings are J90 (underscored)
Package is a 6 pin SOT
This one I suspect is some kind of double transistor

Enclose hand drawing (my camera is busted!)

[image]
[image]
[image]
Thanks for your help

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. You can make identification easier by adding information about the surrounding circuitry. What type of device is it in? Perhaps you can add a partial reverse engineered schematic.

Comment: My camera is not working good cannot make focus on the IC. So I drew it and took a photo. Later I will add a picture. In the meantime, any clues?

Comment: @Ariser Thanks for your reply. J90 IC handles a latching relay so almost sure is a dual transistor, but wanted to know the specs. The other one will have to reverse engineer a bit